# How to flat array of object in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2020

I've a array of object like. i want to extract nested object and return it as expected output. My approach is already not working and also not sure its efficient to iterating on large set of data.

```
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Micheal',
        desc: 'Micheal',
        empObj: {
            empId: 1,
            empName: 'Micheal',
            country: 'UK',
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Allen',
        desc: 'Allen',
        empObj: {
            empId: 2,
            empName: 'Allen',
            country: 'Germany',

        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Rose',
        desc: 'Rose',
        empObj: {
            empId: 3,
            empName: 'Rose',
            country: 'USA',
        }
    }
];
```

I need to flat/ convert the data like

```
[
    {
        name: 'Micheal',
        desc: 'Micheal',
        empId: 1,
        empName: 'Micheal',
        country: 'UK',
    },
    {
        name: 'Allen',
        desc: 'Allen',
        empId: 2,
        empName: 'Allen',
        country: 'Germany',
    },
    
    {
        name: 'Rose',
        desc: 'Rose',    
        empId: 3,
        empName: 'Rose',
        country: 'USA',
    
        
    }
]
```

but I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

```
const expected = Object.keys(data.empObj).reduce(function(r, k) {
  return r.concat(k, object.empObj[k]);
}, []);

console.log('expected', expected);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
data.map(({ name, desc, empObj }) => ({ name, desc, ...empObj }))
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Micheal",
    desc: "Micheal",
    empObj: {
      empId: 1,
      empName: "Micheal",
      country: "UK",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Allen",
    desc: "Allen",
    empObj: {
      empId: 2,
      empName: "Allen",
      country: "Germany",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Rose",
    desc: "Rose",
    empObj: {
      empId: 3,
      empName: "Rose",
      country: "USA",
    },
  },
];

const result = data.map(({ name, desc, empObj }) => ({ name, desc, ...empObj, }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `map()` method along with destructuring and the spread and rest syntax.

We can achieve the desired output by destruturing the `empObj` key and collecting the rest of the properties in the each object in the array using the rest syntax.

Inside the `map()` method's callback function, return a new object, spreading the `empObj` as well as other properties in the newly created object using the spread syntax.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Micheal', desc: 'Micheal', empObj: { empId: 1, empName: 'Micheal', country: 'UK' } },
  { name: 'Allen', desc: 'Allen', empObj: { empId: 2, empName: 'Allen', country: 'Germany' } }
];

const result = data.map(({ empObj, ...rest }) => {
  return { ...rest, ...empObj };
});

console.log(result);
```

---

Reason why your code throws an error is because `data` is an array, so `data.empObj` is undefined and you are passing this undefined value to the `Object.keys(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and `.map()`

`const output = data.map(d => ({name: d.name, desc: d.desc, ...d.empObj}))`